# ¿Cuántos flops usa la raíz cuadrada?

Tags: double

Lo que tengo entendido

- multiplicación, suma y resta: 1 flop
- División 4 flops

Pero sqrt() sé que debe de utilizar más de 1 pero no se cuantos.

Comment: si mal no recuerdo son 5 pero no recuerdo